# how to install appication ipa file in iphone simulater using appium

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, appium-ios

we are going to test our ios mobile application using appium. To test we are using the ios Simulator.
But we are facing the problem while installing the application to the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Use an debug build for iOS automation always , it'll work